# Can one generate an app to sub-directories with "ng generate application"?

Tags: angular-cli, angular8

I'm trying to set up an Angular Workspace and would like to know if it's possible to run the "ng generate application" command to a sub-directory within the projects folder.

I've already tried running it like the "ng generate component" command where you just specify the path like "ng generate component main/sub", but it doesn't seem like "application" has that option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use create the worspace like this:

> ng new worspace-name --create-application=false

go to folder:

> cd workspace-name

then create the application(s) like this:

> ng generate application application-name

check https://angular.io/cli/new and https://angular.io/cli/generate

Comment: I did step 1 and step 2.  I'm just wondering if there's a way to create sub-directories with the ng generate application command.

Comment: With ng generate you can't do it like with components or modules.

Answer (score -4):

I use on daily base the --directory flag to generate apps in subdirectories
e.g. `ng g app hold-my-bier --directory=StupidIdeas`